# How to clone a listview and not reference the previous listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, clone

I am having problems creating a copy of a ListView such that the new copy is not an instance of the original ListView (i.e. when I use methods like `copyOfListView.Items.Clear()` they do not affect both ListViews and only affect the copied ListView). The problem is that I need to copy all of the properties of the original ListView as well as the items and columns, so that the new ListView can be printed with my printer class.
Here's what I have so far:

```
foreach (ColumnHeader cHead in originalList.Columns)
{
    newList.Columns.Add((ColumnHeader)cHead.Clone());
}
foreach (ListViewItem item in originalList.Items)
{
    newList.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
}
```

Is there a fast way to copy all the properties?

Comment: Clone creates only shallow copies, i.e. all references get copied without creating clones of the objects they reference. Most properties like Fonts or Colors etc.. are value types; only a few are reference types, most notably the Items/SubItems themselves. Also, possibly any Tags, depending on what if anything you put there. So you only need to take care of those few exceptions..